# Table-valued parameters into stored procedure using Hibernate

Tags: java, sql, sql-server, hibernate, t-sql

I'm trying to use a table-valued parameter for a stored procedure we're calling using Hibernate's `Session.createSQLQuery`.

I have created a type and stored procedure in SQL:

```
CREATE TYPE StringListType AS TABLE
(
    StringText NVARCHAR(256)
)

CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[TestStringListType]
( 
    @stringList StringListType READONLY
)
AS
    SELECT * FROM @stringList
```

I can use this in SQL with:

```
BEGIN
Declare @StringListTemp As StringListType

insert INTO @StringListTemp (StringText)
values ('foo'), ('bar'), ('baz')

EXEC TestStringListType @StringListTemp
END
```

What I would like to do in Java is something like:

```
String fakeQueryStr = "call TestStringListType :list";
SQLQuery fakeQuery = getSession().createSQLQuery(fakeQueryStr);
ArrayList<String> data = Lists.newArrayList("foo", "bar", "baz");
fakeQuery.setParameter("list", data);
return fakeQuery.list();
```

Neither `setParameter` or `setParameterList` work here of course. How do I map my list of Strings to this type to use as a parameter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was unable to find a solution for this problem as written. My work-around was to copy the entirety of the stored procedure into a string in Java. In the above example, that would mean that I replaced:

```
String fakeQueryStr = "call TestStringListType :list";
```

with

```
String fakeQueryStr = "SELECT * FROM :list";
```

In my actual code, this was undesirable, because the stored procedure was a significantly longer set of statements, but it does still work when wrapped in `BEGIN` and `END` within the string.